# Linking on a Redmine Wiki

Tags: hyperlink, wiki, redmine

I'm writing a wiki on Redmine for the program my company just developed. I've been reading Redmine Wiki formatting pages but I simply can't find how to link to headers on a page that hold spaces.

For example:

This works [[Setup#Oracle|Oracle Setup]]

This does not work [[Setup#Oracle DB|Oracle DB Setup]]

The second I have a header with a space, hyphen, underscore... ANYTHING more than one word, Redmine is unable to link.

Any ideas how to link correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hyphens worked for me using the textile formatting.

```
[[Wiki#Test-link-target|a link]]
```

If you open the wiki page you should see a little paragraph symbol next to each header that appears when you hover your mouse there. That should give you the (semi-)permalink you can use. You can always look at the wiki pages source for the link names.

One problem I remember when working on the Markdown filter was that each text formatter would create it's table of contents separately. So the anchor links for textile might be different than the ones for plain text or Markdown.